# PullToRefresh Gridview on android scroll when refreshing

Tags: android, android-widget

I use [Chris Banes's PullToRefresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). PullToRefreshGridview works fine, but there is a problem. When refreshing, the gridview locked, it can't move. I set `ptrScrollingWhileRefreshingEnabled` as true, the gridview can scroll while refreshing, but the refreshing view is always there, it cannot hide or get smaller like PullToRefreshListview does.

How can I fix it, makes the PullToRefreshGridview works like PullToRefreshListview?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call "onRefreshComplete" method.

for example..

```
@Override
public void onPullDownToRefresh(PullToRefreshBase refreshView) {
    refreshView.onRefreshComplete();
}
```